# using ajax.beginform not rendering view

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, ajax.beginform

I have a partial view that has an Ajax.BeginForm, it renders after clicking on a link, it was working before but I changed it and now its not working, this is what it looks like now:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(
    "AddTimeSeriesData",
    "Employees1Controller",
    new routevalues { },
    new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = domElementId, InsertionMode = InsertionMode.ReplaceWith }, 
    new { id = "ajax_form" }
    )
    )
{
```

is my declaration wrong? Isn't this a valid overload?

when I had the following it worked:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(
    new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = domElementId, InsertionMode = InsertionMode.ReplaceWith }
    )
    )
{
```

Comment: Is your controller really named `Employees1ControllerController`?

Comment: yes, Employees1Controller (you have the word controller typed twice)

Comment: Yes I know :) Change `Employees1Controller` to `Employees1`

Comment: ohhh, let me try that, I'll get back to you! - @StephenMuecke that didn't work :( by the way, the name of my controller class is literally "Employees1Controller" you sure it should be "Employees1"?

Comment: @StephenMuecke here's a question, is there an overload that just has AjaxOptions and the html Attributes (i.e. I want to have an id attribute), I looked online but couldn't figure out which is the right overload

Comment: Your using the correct overload [refer docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470626(v=vs.118).aspx) to render `<form id="ajax_form" ...>` but the second parameter means your have `<form .. action="/Employees1Controller/AddTimeSeriesData"...>` which does not exist

Answer (score 0):

AddTimeSeriesData should be your Action Method on your controller Employees1Controller.

Make sure your contoller name correct, I guess it should be Employees1 and not Employees1Controller.

Since you are doing nothing on parameter three (new routevalues) remove it.

Hope fully it will work for you.